# JavaScript (p5.js) doesn't work on mobile

Tags: javascript, mobile, p5.js

[my site](http://marvinenrico.cf)
So I made my site with almost full javascript, everything works well on my pc but it shows white screen on mobile devices, I have no idea what's wrong

Comment: It shows white screen (and empty source code) on my pc...

Comment: Yeah, I don't see anything when I go to that URL. Not even an HTML file. Are you sure you have everything configured correctly?

Comment: so just debug the error on your mobile device. if you get an android device follow these instructions to setup mobile device debugging https://www.addictivetips.com/android/get-web-console-log-chrome-for-android/, then share your error here